# How to use python to push a photo set to webrtc for video playback?

Tags: python, webrtc, video-streaming

I have some pictures, and I need to develop a server by myself to push these pictures to webtrc and play them on the web page.

I can push the images that opencv reads to the rtmp server via ffmpeg, but how do I push them to webrtc?

Could you help me look at this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you already try the examples of aiortc?

Comment: https://github.com/supersjgk/LiveStream-WebRTC-Flask-OpenCV,I have seen this example, but there is no way to do the on-demand effect or live effect.What I want is an effect similar to ffmpeg push video streams, with direct access to the video stream address to play the video.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GStreamer for this use case - something like multifilesrc as an input (depending on your file flow) and Webrtcbin as an output. Note, that it's not possible to work with Webrtcbin from command line, so you'll need to construct and operate with pipeline from your Python app.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that. What I want is an effect similar to ffmpeg push video streams, with direct access to the video stream address to play the video.github.com/supersjgk/LiveStream-WebRTC-Flask-OpenCV. Thanks.